# Why mbasic version of Facebook goes only to 3 depth of members section?

Tags: web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I know this is not programming but I didn't find any api for developers in facebook. So for that i'm using basic version of facebook. But problem is that i can't go more than three pages of facebook groups members.
Ex : https://mbasic.facebook.com/groups/2680624942197490?view=members&refid=18

If I click on "see all" then i can click only 3 times i.e only shows approx 120-130 members but in [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com) verison there is all members.

Is that they desigined it like this?
If yes, is there any api to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer : Yes, They have did it like this.
You can use `Group - Graph Api` For this but it need to be approved.

Comment: Then how do i send requests to facebook server directly to get data?